# Can't increase ADB buffer size from android application

Tags: android, shell, adb

I was able to increase ADB buffer size from ADB shell using following command: `logcat -G 10M`.

But if I run this same command inside a android app(android terminal app https://f-droid.org/en/packages/jackpal.androidterm/) I get following error `failed to set the 'main' log size`.

How can I do it?

Comment: Why would you expect that to work?  Adb on the phone and adb on your PC are different programs.  I can't think of a valid reason why you would ever want to set the log size in an app.

Comment: @GabeSechan Okay. I wanted to remotely collect ADB logs in case of issues. The bigger the buffer is, more helps on debugging. I run a always on native (jni/c++) service on a custom android device.

Comment: If you're remotely collecting them, add the command to the PC side, not the app side

Comment: Apps do not longer have access to logcat. Only with a special permission you can access the logcat output of the app itself but not of all apps (and thus I don't think you can change any configuration options of the main logcat log).